# Default positioning of fill characters for streams

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, iomanip

On the reference page for [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill), there is an example similar to the following program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(10) << 42 << '\n';
}
```

which claims that it should print:

```
********42
```

This suggests that the default positioning of the fill characters is as if the [`std::right`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) manipulator was used.

Does the standard guarantee that this is the behavior, or do I need to specify `std::right` to be sure?

Also, does this work for just `std::cout`, or is it the same for any output stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setfill` is defined in [[std.manip]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std.manip) as

```
template<class charT, class traits>
void f(basic_ios<charT, traits>& str, charT c) {
  // set fill character
  str.fill(c);
}
```

so we need to look at what happens to an `ostream`'s `fill` function and that is detailed in [[ostream.formatted.reqmts]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ostream.formatted.reqmts#3) as

> If a formatted output function of a stream os determines padding, it does so as follows. Given a `charT` character sequence seq where `charT` is the character type of the stream, if the length of seq is less than `os.width()`, then enough copies of `os.fill()` are added to this sequence as necessary to pad to a width of `os.width()` characters. If `(os.flags() & ios_­base​::​adjustfield) == ios_­base​::​left` is `true`, the fill characters are placed after the character sequence; otherwise, they are placed before the character sequence.

So unless `left` is specified, the fill character come first.  By default, `left` is not a set flag for `cout` and this is detail in [Table 122: basic_­ios​::​init() effects   [tab:basic.ios.cons]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.ios.cons#tab:basic.ios.cons)